# getting ids of different textViews defined in a class

Tags: java, android

My TextView class is

```
static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView tv0;
        protected TextView tv1;
        protected TextView tv2;
        protected TextView tv3;
        protected TextView tv4;
        protected TextView tv5;
        protected TextView tv6;
        protected TextView tv7; 
    }

linearview.setTag(viewHolder);
linearView.setId(xyz);
```

// viewHolder.tv5 id will be xyz+5

Now, I can get the whole class with view.getTag. what i want is, suppose i have a word "TEST"

my random function selects 2 so i want tv2 = T, tv3 = E and so on. I can use str.getCharAt to get the char but how to get textViews from random word.

Best Regards

Comment: Did you try to put the TextViews in an array?

Comment: ehm no, i haven't so far. I have made a class as you know that

Comment: @slybloty i have made layout.xml for 7 textViews, calling it again and again and adding it in my linear layout . View view = null;
  LayoutInflater inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
  view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.words, null);
  final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right....

Within the class you can simply write:

```
TextView[] views = new TextView[]{tv0,tv1,tv2,tv3,etc.};
```

And then write a getter:

```
public TextView[] views(){ return views; }
```

Alternatively, instead of making them protected, you make them public. (only if changing their values directly without having to change anything else is ok)

Answer (score 0):

Thy this:

```
static class ViewHolder {
        private ArrayList<TextView> tv = new ArrayList<TextView>();

        public void addTV(TextView newTV)
        {
            tv.add(newTV);
        }

        public TextView getTVat(int i)
        {
            return tv.get(i);
        }

}
```